# acclivity of differential equation not defined

Tags: definition

the differential equation y'*y=cos(x) has the acclivity of y'=cos(x)/y.
Obviously the acclivity is not defined for points (x=r;y=0). r= real numbers

Is there a way to give a short but logic argument for this?
Does this mean there is no kurve within the infinite array of curves, that
goes through null (crossing the x-axis) ?

Id be gereat if sombody could give me an answer.

Best Regard,

Jln